# MATLAB Maximum recursion limit reached with ode45

Tags: matlab, recursion

The following code will not run properly because the ode45 is reaching its maximum recursion limit does anyone know why? I am very new to matlab.

```
   function hw8 = HW8(~,t,x)
x = [0,0]
Tbar = [294.4266 429.9139 582.6765]
CAbar = [.9422 .7661 .5675]
DHp=-1000;
k0tau=10.;
Ep=1500;
Chi=0.3;
Tc=250;
Cai=0;
Ca=x(1);
T=x(2);
r=k0tau*exp(-Ep/T)*Ca;
dCa = (Cai-Ca)-r;
dT = -(1+Chi)*(T-Tc)+DHp*r;
hw8 = [dCa;dT]

[t,x] = ode45(HW8,[0 1],[.1 250])
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `HW8` as one of the arguments to `ode45`, the function is called before `ode45` is executed and creates an infinite recursion:

1. Execute `HW8`.
2. `ode45`'s first argument is a function call to `HW8`
3. Execute `HW8`.
4. `ode45`'s first argument is a function call to `HW8`
5. Execute `HW8`.
6. `ode45`'s first argument ... (*ad infinitum*)

This is the nature of stacks and actually a feature since a first argument function call could return a handle for use with `ode45`.  But not in this case since it is an infinite recursion, which isn't detected.

The solution is to separate the function calling `ode45` from the function calculating the right-hand side handle given to `ode45`:

```
function [t,x] = HW8()

    [t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) rhs(t,x),[0 1],[.1 250]);

end

function dxdt = rhs(~,x)
    Tbar = [294.4266 429.9139 582.6765];
    CAbar = [.9422 .7661 .5675];
    DHp=-1000;
    k0tau=10.;
    Ep=1500;
    Chi=0.3;
    Tc=250;
    Cai=0;
    Ca=x(1);
    T=x(2);
    r=k0tau*exp(-Ep/T)*Ca;
    dCa = (Cai-Ca)-r;
    dT = -(1+Chi)*(T-Tc)+DHp*r;
    dxdt = [dCa;dT];
end
```